# Look up sum_range programmatically

Tags: excel-2010

I'm using the `sumif` function, and instead of hardcoding what the `range` and `sum_range` cell ranges are, I want to look them up using something like `match.` Basically, the column that will be my `sum_range` has a column header that I could look up, so in pseudo code, what I want to be able to do is:

1. Find the column header for the range I want to sum
2. Once that column is found, select the entire column as the range
3. Use this newly found range as either my `range` or `sum_range` for the `sumif` function

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `Find the column header for the range I want to sum`, and how  do you presume this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the following example and adapt it to your needs:

[image: Excel Formula for Match-Index-Sum]

```
= SUM(INDEX(A2:C5;;MATCH(F2;A1:C1)))
```

- `Match()` selects the desired column (as given by cell `F2`)
- `Index()` then cuts this column from the given array
- `Sum()` does the sum - I used the sum function but you may take any function you like

Comment: sorry, not sure how to interpret `![Excel Formula for Match-Index-Sum][1]`